# Proving that a subset $B$ is also a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just came across a question in a practice exam that asks:

Let $B = \{1, t-1, (t-1)^2\}$ be a subset of $P_2$ (all polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2).
Prove that $B$ is also a basis for $P_2$.

What I tried was putting each vector as a column vector into a $3 \times 3$ matrix, and then row reducing it which gave the identity matrix for $\mathbb{R}^3$. But I'm not sure if that means anything. How would I go about proving this? Thanks!

Comment: As a consequence of the replacement theorem, it suffices to show that $B=\{1,t-1,(t-1)^2\}$ is linearly independent using the fact that $\{1,t,t^2\}$ is linearly independent and the standard basis for $P_2$ to prove that $B$ is a basis for $P_2$.

Answer (score 1):

What you did means something - It does not matter that it was the identity matrix, but it does matter that the matrix was invertible - this means that those vectors (polynomials in our case) are linearly independent. Row reduction was redundant. You could have just calculated the determinant of this matrix.

Since we know that the dimension of the space of all polynomials degree 2 or below is $3$, and we have $3$ independent vectors in that space, we can infer that it is indeed a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Well you only have to show that $B$ spans $\{1,t,t^2\}$. But $t = (t-1)+1$ and $t^2 = (t-1)^2 - 2(t+1) + -3(1)$, so you're done.

To understand what you result means, see Oria's answer.